# Scrapy why my spider don't follow to next page?

Tags: python, scrapy

My spider isn't crawling horizontaly, and I can't figure out why.

`parse_item` function is working pretty well on the first page. I've checked the xpath of `next_page` in the scrapy shell, and it is correct.

Could you please check my code?

The website I'm trying to scrape is [this](https://www.vivareal.com.br/venda/minas-gerais/belo-horizonte/)

```
import scrapy
import datetime
import socket

from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from itemloaders.processors import MapCompose
from properties.items import PropertiesItem


class EasySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'easy'
    allowed_domains = ['www.vivareal.com.br']
    start_urls = ['https://www.vivareal.com.br/venda/minas-gerais/belo-horizonte/']

    next_page = '//li[@class="pagination__item"][last()]'

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=next_page)),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'/imovel/', 
                            deny=r'/imoveis-lancamento/'),
                            callback='parse_item'),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        l = ItemLoader(item=PropertiesItem(), response=response)
        l.add_xpath('url', 'a/@href', )
        l.add_xpath('tipo', '//h1/text()',
                    MapCompose(lambda x: x.strip().split()[0]))
        l.add_xpath('valor', '//h3[@class="price__price-info js-price-sale"]/text()',
                    MapCompose(lambda x: x.strip().replace('R$ ', '').replace('.', ''), float))
        l.add_xpath('condominio', '//span[@class="price__list-value condominium js-condominium"]/text()',
                    MapCompose(lambda x: x.strip().replace('R$ ', '').replace('.', ''), float))
        l.add_xpath('endereco', '//p[@class="title__address js-address"]/text()',
                    MapCompose(lambda x: x.split(' - ')[0]))
        l.add_xpath('bairro', '//p[@class="title__address js-address"]/text()',
                    MapCompose(lambda x: x.split(' - ')[1].split(',')[0]))
        l.add_xpath('quartos', '//ul[@class="features"]/li[@title="Quartos"]/span/text()',
                    MapCompose(lambda x: x.strip(), int))
        l.add_xpath('banheiros', '//ul[@class="features"]/li[@title="Banheiros"]/span/text()',
                    MapCompose(lambda x: x.strip(), int))
        l.add_xpath('vagas', '//ul[@class="features"]/li[@title="Vagas"]/span/text()',
                    MapCompose(lambda x: x.strip(), int))
        l.add_xpath('area', '//ul[@class="features"]/li[@title="Área"]/span/text()',
                    MapCompose(lambda x: x.strip(), float))
        l.add_value('url', response.url)
        
        # Housekeeping fields
        l.add_value('project', self.settings.get('BOT_NAME'))
        l.add_value('spider', self.name)
        l.add_value('server', socket.gethostname())
        l.add_value('date', datetime.datetime.now())
        
        return l.load_item()
```

**UPDATE**

Searching the log I found this about the horizontal crawl:

```
2021-02-22 17:09:24 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.vivareal.com.br/venda/minas-gerais/belo-horizonte/#pagina=2> (referer: https://www.vivareal.com.br/venda/minas-gerais/belo-horizonte/)
2021-02-22 17:09:24 [scrapy.dupefilters] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET https://www.vivareal.com.br/venda/minas-gerais/belo-horizonte/#pagina=2> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
```

It seems like next page is been duplicate, but I don't know how to fix it.

In addition, I realize that, dispite the `href` points to `#pagina=2`, the actual url is `?pagina=2`.

Any hints?

Comment: Please share the url that you are crawling. A spider's behavior heavily depends on the behavior of the website

Comment: thank you Ryan, I just updated the answer with the url

Answer (score 1):

Actually your spider is not crawling even the first page.

The problem resides in **allowed_domains** parameter. Change it to

```py
allowed_domains = ['www.vivareal.com.br']
```

and you will start to crawl. After that change you will get a lot of errors (exceptions thrown by the code due to logical errors, as I saw here), but your code will be running as intended.

**EDIT (2)**:

check the LOGs:

```
2021-02-22 13:36:19 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.vivareal.com.br': <GET https://www.vivareal.com.br/venda/minas-gerais/belo-horizonte/#pagina=2>
```

Basically the **allowed_domains** is not properly set, as explained [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/994mig/using_scrapy_recursively/) and on [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862474/following-hyperlink-and-filtered-offsite-request).

**EDIT**:
to make it **clear**: the log I get after running the spider as defined on the question is:

```
2021-02-22 13:29:18 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.4.1 started (bot: properties)
2021-02-22 13:29:18 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.2.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.8.1 (default, Feb  9 2020, 21:34:32) - [GCC 7.4.0], pyOpenSSL 20.0.1 (OpenSSL 1.1.1i  8 Dec 2020), cryptography 3.3.1, Platform Linux-4.15.0-135-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.27
2021-02-22 13:29:18 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor
2021-02-22 13:29:18 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'properties',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'properties.spiders',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['properties.spiders']}
2021-02-22 13:29:18 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 3790c3525890efea
2021-02-22 13:29:18 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2021-02-22 13:29:18 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2021-02-22 13:29:18 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2021-02-22 13:29:18 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2021-02-22 13:29:18 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2021-02-22 13:29:18 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2021-02-22 13:29:18 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2021-02-22 13:29:19 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.vivareal.com.br/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2021-02-22 13:29:20 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.vivareal.com.br/venda/minas-gerais/belo-horizonte/> (referer: None)
2021-02-22 13:29:20 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.vivareal.com.br': <GET https://www.vivareal.com.br/venda/minas-gerais/belo-horizonte/#pagina=2>
2021-02-22 13:29:20 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2021-02-22 13:29:20 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 606,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 156997,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 1.87473,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 22, 16, 29, 20, 372722),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'memusage/max': 54456320,
 'memusage/startup': 54456320,
 'offsite/domains': 1,
 'offsite/filtered': 34,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 22, 16, 29, 18, 497992)}
2021-02-22 13:29:20 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

and when I run **with the proposed changes** the log is this (adapted to not show my paths):

```
2021-02-22 13:31:47 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.4.1 started (bot: properties)
2021-02-22 13:31:47 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.2.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.8.1 (default, Feb  9 2020, 21:34:32) - [GCC 7.4.0], pyOpenSSL 20.0.1 (OpenSSL 1.1.1i  8 Dec 2020), cryptography 3.3.1, Platform Linux-4.15.0-135-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.27
2021-02-22 13:31:47 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor
2021-02-22 13:31:47 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'properties',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'properties.spiders',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['properties.spiders']}
2021-02-22 13:31:47 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 65a5f31c8dda80fa
2021-02-22 13:31:47 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2021-02-22 13:31:47 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2021-02-22 13:31:47 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2021-02-22 13:31:47 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2021-02-22 13:31:47 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2021-02-22 13:31:47 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2021-02-22 13:31:47 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2021-02-22 13:31:49 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.vivareal.com.br/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2021-02-22 13:31:49 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.vivareal.com.br/venda/minas-gerais/belo-horizonte/> (referer: None)
2021-02-22 13:31:49 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.vivareal.com.br/venda/minas-gerais/belo-horizonte/#pagina=2> (referer: https://www.vivareal.com.br/venda/minas-gerais/belo-horizonte/)
2021-02-22 13:31:50 [scrapy.dupefilters] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET https://www.vivareal.com.br/venda/minas-gerais/belo-horizonte/#pagina=2> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
2021-02-22 13:31:50 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.vivareal.com.br/imovel/apartamento-1-quartos-funcionarios-bairros-belo-horizonte-com-garagem-41m2-venda-RS330000-id-2510414426/> (referer: https://www.vivareal.com.br/venda/minas-gerais/belo-horizonte/)
2021-02-22 13:31:50 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.vivareal.com.br/imovel/apartamento-3-quartos-nova-granada-bairros-belo-horizonte-com-garagem-74m2-venda-RS499000-id-2509923918/> (referer: https://www.vivareal.com.br/venda/minas-gerais/belo-horizonte/)
2021-02-22 13:31:50 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.vivareal.com.br/imovel/apartamento-4-quartos-serra-bairros-belo-horizonte-com-garagem-246m2-venda-RS1950000-id-2510579983/> (referer: https://www.vivareal.com.br/venda/minas-gerais/belo-horizonte/)
2021-02-22 13:31:50 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.vivareal.com.br/imovel/casa-3-quartos-sao-geraldo-bairros-belo-horizonte-com-garagem-120m2-venda-RS460000-id-2484383176/> (referer: https://www.vivareal.com.br/venda/minas-gerais/belo-horizonte/)
2021-02-22 13:31:50 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.vivareal.com.br/imovel/apartamento-4-quartos-savassi-bairros-belo-horizonte-com-garagem-206m2-venda-RS1790000-id-2503711314/> (referer: https://www.vivareal.com.br/venda/minas-gerais/belo-horizonte/)
2021-02-22 13:31:50 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.vivareal.com.br/imovel/apartamento-2-quartos-paqueta-bairros-belo-horizonte-com-garagem-60m2-venda-RS260000-id-2479637684/> (referer: https://www.vivareal.com.br/venda/minas-gerais/belo-horizonte/)
2021-02-22 13:31:50 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.vivareal.com.br/imovel/apartamento-3-quartos-savassi-bairros-belo-horizonte-com-garagem-107m2-venda-RS1250000-id-2506122689/> (referer: https://www.vivareal.com.br/venda/minas-gerais/belo-horizonte/)
2021-02-22 13:31:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.vivareal.com.br/imovel/apartamento-1-quartos-funcionarios-bairros-belo-horizonte-com-garagem-41m2-venda-RS330000-id-2510414426/> (referer: https://www.vivareal.com.br/venda/minas-gerais/belo-horizonte/)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 120, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/utils/python.py", line 353, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/utils/python.py", line 353, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 62, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 62, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 340, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 62, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 62, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 62, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/crawl.py", line 114, in _parse_response
    cb_res = callback(response, **cb_kwargs) or ()
  File "/home/leomaffei/properties/properties/spiders/spider.py", line 28, in parse_item
    l.add_xpath('url', 'a/@href', )
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/itemloaders/__init__.py", line 350, in add_xpath
    self.add_value(field_name, values, *processors, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/itemloaders/__init__.py", line 190, in add_value
    self._add_value(field_name, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/itemloaders/__init__.py", line 208, in _add_value
    processed_value = self._process_input_value(field_name, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/itemloaders/__init__.py", line 312, in _process_input_value
    proc = self.get_input_processor(field_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/itemloaders/__init__.py", line 290, in get_input_processor
    proc = self._get_item_field_attr(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/itemloaders/__init__.py", line 308, in _get_item_field_attr
    field_meta = ItemAdapter(self.item).get_field_meta(field_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/itemadapter/adapter.py", line 235, in get_field_meta
    return self.adapter.get_field_meta(field_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/itemadapter/adapter.py", line 161, in get_field_meta
    return MappingProxyType(self.item.fields[field_name])
KeyError: 'url'
2021-02-22 13:31:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.vivareal.com.br/imovel/apartamento-3-quartos-nova-granada-bairros-belo-horizonte-com-garagem-74m2-venda-RS499000-id-2509923918/> (referer: https://www.vivareal.com.br/venda/minas-gerais/belo-horizonte/)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 120, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/utils/python.py", line 353, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/utils/python.py", line 353, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 62, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 62, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 340, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 62, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filte
...
```

Comment: I made the changes, but it's still crawling only page one. I checked the log, and it appears that the spider is capturing the next page but the server is returning the original page: `2021-02-22 11:09:35 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.vivareal.com.br/venda/minas-gerais/belo-horizonte/#pagina=2> (referer: https://www.vivareal.com.br/venda/minas-gerais/belo-horizonte/)
`

Comment: @Marcelo isn't that because the exceptions raised? I suppose the exception thrown at **l.add_xpath('url', 'a/@href', )** causes the whole code below it to fail and then the **return l.load_item()** is not executed. Maybe this could be the cause afterall?

Comment: what exceptions? checking the log of my crawler I found no such exceptions. It captures the `url` field correctly.

Comment: as I said, the code parses all first page, capture the link to all property pages, and save the itens correctly. It cannot, however, go horizontaly, to page 2.

Comment: I edited my answer to better make me understand

Comment: @Marcelo says the log ```2021-02-22 13:36:18 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
```

Comment: it's very strange, because this is not at all what happens here. I commented the `l.add_xpath('url', 'a/@href', )` line but it still only scrape the first page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229049/discussion-between-leonardo-maffei-and-marcelo).