# when I run command 'scrapy crawl Admission' on the error occoured is Filtered offsite request to 'www.worldomets.info'

Tags: python, scrapy

```
import scrapy
class AdmissionsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Admissions'
    allowed_domains = ["www.worldometers.info"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.worldometers.info/population/countries-in-asia-by-population/']

    def parse(self, response):
        countries=response.xpath("//td/a")
        for country in countries:
            name=country.xpath(".//text()").get()
            links=country.xpath(".//@href").get()
            absolute_url=f"https://www.worldomets.info{links}"
            yield scrapy.Request(url=absolute_url)
```

I am traying to print countries name but it show mw the error Filtered offsite request to 'www.worldomets.info': <GET [https://www.worldomets.info/world-population/china-population/>](https://www.worldomets.info/world-population/china-population/%3E)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it like is

```
import scrapy
class AdmissionsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Admissions'
    allowed_domains = ["worldometers.info"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.worldometers.info/population/countries-in-asia-by-population/']

    def parse(self, response):
        countries=response.xpath("//td/a")
        for country in countries:
            name=country.xpath(".//text()").get()
            link=country.xpath(".//@href").get()
            link = response.urljoin(link)
            # print(link)
            # absolute_url=f"https://www.worldomets.info{links}"
            yield scrapy.Request(url=link, callback=self.parse_absoluteurl)

    def parse_absoluteurl(self, response):
        print('\n', response.url ,'\n')
```

for the details [Following hyperlink and "Filtered offsite request"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862474/following-hyperlink-and-filtered-offsite-request)